# php trim function in middle clause

Tags: php

for examples i have this text:

" cat car dog... ".

Impossible that trim function delete all space: "catcardog...".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$output = str_replace(' ', '', $input);
```

`str_replace` will replace all occurrences and not just those immediately at the begin and end of the string.

Comment: Yeah PHP has got a whole whack of good string handling functions to use. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php 

Read a bit through the documentation and you'll find some really great ones